# Data in a list object is being replaced by the latest values.

Tags: c#, list, collections

The newly added data to a list replaces the previous values in a `list<>`.
In the following piece of code all the items in the  `listRM` contain `Address` info. What am i doing wrong?

```
 public void Assign(Rprts PrevItem, Rprts CurrentItem, List<Fields> listRM)
        {
            Fields field = new Fields();
            field.hding = "Name :";
            field.FName = PrevItem.fname;
            field.LName = PrevItem.lname;
            field.addrs1 = "";
            field.addrs2 = "";
            field.City = "";


            listRM.Add(field);


            field.hding = "Address :";
            field.Qty = "";
            field.Name = "";
            field.Dept = "";
            field.addrs1 = "ABC";
            field.addrs2 = "XYZ";
            field.City = "UVW";
            listRM.Add(field);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new `Field` instance for every entry you want to add.

The first time you call `listRM.Add(field)`, you pass a [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) to your `field` object (which also is just a reference). When you alter this object, the object the list points to also changes.

You can see this by putting a breakpont before the second call to `listRM.Add(field)` and inspect both `field`'s and `listRM.Results`'s values, for example but not necessarily using [QuickWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2.aspx).

Now to start creating a new item, just do:

```
field = new Field();
field. // set properties again
listRM.Add(field);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created ONE instance of `Fields` class and added the same object to the list twice modifying that object in the middle. So your list, as expected, would contain that object twice, but both list items will point to the same modified instance `field`.
Try creating brand new objects for every item you intend to add to the list:
`Fields field = new Fields();`